# Where does OrFox save images?

Tags: firefox-for-android, tor

OrFox 1.0beta1 has a function to save images. Yet, there's no information where the image is stored inside and outside the application nor a configuration option to pre-determine the storage location. Maybe someone can share this well-hidden information.

Saved pictures don't appear in a gallery application which searches in default pathes which makes it possible that they're not saved at all and no error message is shown to the user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not store the images. I agree that the option should be removed or at least give you some error when you try to use it.

Details in ["How to save images while using Orweb?" on Tor SE](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/how-to-save-images-while-using-orweb).

Not being too trusty about this, I checked all the locations associated to Orfox and those folders were empty.